# How do I match my windows laptop monitor to match a particular printer profile?

Tags: windows, printing, printer, images, colors

I am using a canon, inkjet, Pixma 3010 printer. But I think that this issue is common across all printers.

While printing a pdf file which contains comics, I notice that the colors are quite dull and there seems to be a slightly high gamma.

I'm printing with all default settings for "photo" mode, printing on a cardstock paper at highest quality.

I've tried printing via ms word (image paste), direct image print on windows and through pdf. The result seems to be the same across them all.

But I read somewhere that this seems to be a common problem with printers. Does anyone know how I can print image that don't have colors dulled out (vibrant colours) and reduce the gamma? The printer advanced properties did not give any such option. It once allows fiddling with brightness/contrast settings.

**Edit:** I came to know that one solution to this is to match the monitor to a printer profile so that we can see exactly what will get printed.

Can someone please help answer how do I match my windows laptop monitor to match a particular printer profile?

Comment: The problem is digital display screens us the RGB color-model for screen display. And just because a color can exist in RGB on the screen does not mean it can be recreated in print via a CMYK color-model used by all printers. This can’t be “fixed” since many web comics are designed to just be displayed on a screen.

Comment: Screens often have different color gamuts than printers, especially 4-color printers. Sometimes photo-specialized 6-color printers can do better. Also, backlights shining through color LCDs can send a lot more light into your eyes than what ink on paper can reflect into your eyes. So screen images are able to be brighter than printed images.

Comment: Basically, what others are saying is that the problem is with your screen recreating the colors, not the printer. More or less. You may wish to rephrase your question to ask how to color calibrate your screen so that it is accurate, and then a second question about how to get your printer output to match the colors you see on the screen. Note, however, that this is an involved process that professional outfits spend large amounts of money doing right, and at best you'll be able to get a poor approximation of on regular home devices.

Comment: @music2myear I think we are more saying regular printers dont have the ability to render as many colors a a screen. Its not a screen calibration issue as much as a printer limitation.

Comment: I came to know of another route that I could take. If I could match my screen to my printer profile that could help because at least if I can see what's going to print, I can tweak the contrast/brightness of the image much better so that I can get a print with good colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've solved this problem to quite a good extent. Davidgo's answer was the starting point. But it's much more than that. Here's the solution that I've found and what I've learned after a lot of reading on this topic:

- **A monitor' contrast** is typically very high. It ranges from **1-1000** ratio. (I'm not aiming for exact numbers or their variations. That is not important here).
- **A printing paper's contrast** is much lower (because it reflects light as compared to emitting it). Its contrast ratio can typically be **1-30** .

With these numbers, you can get a feel of what's going to happen to your image when you print them. Your image is going to lose a considerable amount of contrast and color because the paper is a different material. This is the key.

- There are other things as well, like RGB to CMYK. But that doesn't cause the dull colors. That causes a slight shift in colors. But we're talking about small sizes from a home printer. I'm not talking about professional printing. Perhaps on an A4, A5, or smaller. The color difference wasn't so much (at least based on what I saw) when I tried printing images by converting them to CMYK first.

**So how can I print better colors and contrast on the paper?**

Here's the solution that I've found works.

**Step1:**

Match your monitor's contrast as closely as possible with the paper's contrast.

Here's a guide: http://www.colorwiki.com/wiki/How_To_Get_My_Monitor_To_Match_My_Printer

**Step2:**

Now that you know what your image will look like somewhat after printing (again, I'm not talking about professional printing, I'm talking about home inkjet printers), the first thing that you will notice is that you can barely make out the image.

Now we can tweak that image.

Increase the **image saturation**. Until you can see the colors well.

**Step3:**

Now apply either a **lighten filter** or play with **brightness/contrast** until you can see the image clearer.

**Note:**

Do not make changes repeatedly on the image otherwise, it will become hard to replicate. For example, increasing saturation by 30 and again by 30 is not the same as increasing it by 60 in one go. I realized this through trial and error.

Hence, if you are not satisfied with the image, then undo it untill before step#2. And repeat steps 2 and 3. Keep doing this until you arrive at an image that looks reasonably good. Save it.

I tried this out and the image didn't look good on the monitor. It easily looked over-saturated and over-bright. But when I printed them they came out beautifully on the paper.

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying a bit - The RGB color range (ie colors you see on a screen) is bigger then the CMYK range (colors you can print), and this is likely a good chunk of the problem.

Programs like Photoshop (the gold Standard) and GIMP (Free - what I use) allow you to modify the colors.  While there are more expert ways of doing it - especially as its a comic - you may be able to get away with modifying the color curves, hue, saturation, brightness which may help you modify the image so it will print better.

Comment: Yup. This. Without going into mind-numbing detail, this is it. CMYK simply is not capable of the gamut of even internet-basic sRGB. Don't even waste time trying. It is not physically possible.

Comment: The paper quality plays a big role here too, "plain paper" cannot show what e.g .Epson Lustre does. Now you may screen grab comics images and try turn up contrast and saturation in e.g. Gimp.

Comment: I won't buy Inkjets because for most cases they are bad tech -  and I dont do much with printing graphics - so my experience is with lasers.  Laminating color Laser prints makes a huge difference to how they look.  I wonder if - similar to using high gloss paper - laminating inkjet prints may improve them as well.  (I comment that ignoring high end commercial $$$$ lasers, Color laser prints of photographs suck compared to inkjet so there is more room for improvement, but it might be worth trying in some use cases)

Comment: @Hannu - nowhere near as much influence as CMYK has. I do a lot of commercial printing [& used to actually be an offset litho machine op] & do use one print service who can use sRGB input, but I'm always careful to check my gamut before submitting jobs. A consumer unaware of the 'drop' in gamut from one to the other will often be surprised by the output. It's the cause of many complaints - all unfounded. You can 'brighten things up' with good profiling, good paper, laminating etc, but you cannot achieve sRGB on even CcMmYyK no matter what you do.

Comment: Consumer printers will invariably be a whole lot worse than commercial. You could do far worse than just take it to your local 'Snappy Snaps' instead.

Comment: Can't I just convert an image to CMYK format in that case? If I could visually see what it looks like then I could better adjust the image.

Comment: @davidgo As a matter of fact, I did laminate a printed photo recently. Hot lamination, 125ul I believe. But it made the image look a lot worse (printed from the inkjet).

Comment: @Mugen - its beyond my knowledge (I'm not a graphic or print designer), but I believe there are options to change the color profile on GIMP to CMYK. https://daviesmediadesign.com/where-to-download-cmyk-color-profiles-for-gimp/

Comment: “Can't I just convert an image to CMYK format in that case?” Yeah, you can try and convert an RGB image to CMYK. But in my experience with Photoshop, the second you do this the colors of the image on your screen will look as dull as the image you are printing out. Meaning when you convert to CMYK on screen it is not much different than covering from RGB to CMYK when you print. There is no magic spell here: CMYK encompasses a more limited color range than RGB does.

Comment: I came to know of another route that I could take. If I could match my screen to my printer profile that could help because at least if I can see what's going to print, I can tweak the contrast/brightness of the image much better so that I can get a print with good colors.

Comment: @Mugen Cool! And now you know what color calibration of a screen does; it is done for cases exactly like that.